# How dynamic set double click on MenuItem

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I do project in JSF with PrimeFaces element. I created my `MenuItem` dynamic:

```
DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem();
            item.setValue(name);
            model.addElement(item);
            item.setCommand("#{myIndexBean.display}");
            item.setUpdate("dsh");
```

Now I want set programmatically double click action on this event and after double click I want edit name of this `MenuItem`. This is my `xhtml` fragment:

```xml
<pe:layoutPane position="north" resizable="false" closable="false"
                spacingOpen="0" spacingClosed="0"
                styleClassContent="ctl-context-btns-pane">

                <h:form id="frmBtnsFORM">

                    <p:menubar id="btnsFORM" model="#{myIndexBean.model}"
                        styleClass="ctl-context-btns-bar km-context-btns-tab">

                    </p:menubar>
                </h:form>
            </pe:layoutPane>
```

Comment: please add your `XHTML`

Comment: how would you do a dbl-click in xhtml?

Comment: generally when you use a `Primefaces` component you can directly use `dbclick` i mean it's provided with the composant, but in other case (in your case) you can add `<p:ajax/>` and make an event `doubleclick` hope that helped

Comment: @YagamiLight I want this efect after double click my MenuItem http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inplace.xhtml

Comment: and what is the problem you can apply it if `Primefaces` give it as an example

Comment: @YagamiLight but I want set this element `inplace` in java code and set it on my MenuItem

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand, i am tiered if i understand you want to make New york paris ... dynamically

Comment: @YagamiLight ok, Idea is: I have list of object and I created MenuBar with names of this objects like tab1, tab2... User can add new tab so I can't create it in xhtml because I don't know amount of my tab. But my problem is how I can set this inplace on tab and change it name so I think, inplace on tab must be set in Java code. Do you know what I want?

Comment: if i understand when someone click on the submenu it change the menubar label ?!?

Comment: @YagamiLight no menubarlabel, menuItem label

Comment: So you'd like to set the label of a menu item in the menu bar just like you can rename files in e.g. windows. Click twice (slowly, to not make it a doubleclick) on the header and you want an input field to be shown where you can edit the label). Well, that is not directly possible and would require a fair amount of code. To much to be a 'simple' answer.